# Three.js MeshStandardMaterial issue chrome on Mac m1

Tags: typescript, three.js

I have a problem. In chrome on m1 mac my scene looks like [image: screenshot from chrome]
However in safari or firefox everything is fine
[image: screenshot from firefox]

This is my code for rendering walls

```
    const wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        color: color,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        precision: "highp",
   
    });
```

And this is my code for rendering material

```
 if (item3d instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        item3d.material.opacity = item.opacity;
        item3d.material.transparent = true;
        item3d.material.polygonOffset = false;
        item3d.material.polygonOffsetFactor = 5.0;
        item3d.material.polygonOffsetUnits = 5.0;
        item3d.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        item3d.material.precision = "highp";
        item3d.userData.initColor = item3d.material.color?.getHex();
    }
```

P.s. if I add `transparent: true` in `MeshStandardMaterial` it would be better in rendering walls but in object interaction its's worse
[image]

Comment: It seems this glitch needs to be reported to the Chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: I think it's not because in another web-application everything is fine

Comment: But when other devices don't show the glitch with the same app it can't be an issue in the engine.

Comment: What ist the distance to the near and far plane of the perspektive camera? Reduce the distance to the far plane and increase the distance to the near plane (if possible).

Comment: Can you please check if the issue disappears by using Chrome Canary and forcing the Metal backend like so: Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --user-data-dir=/tmp/c1 --use-angle=metal

Comment: I am sorry, but I open in terminal Applications folder and  i haven't Google inside there. Maybe I misunderstood you

Answer (score 0):

Following @Mugen87 suggestion, I went to https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/ and downloaded and installed Chrome Canary Version 111.0.5544.0 (Official Build) canary (x86_64) for MacOS Monterey (Version 12.6.2 (21G320) - 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9).

I then launched it via terminal CLI and it works fine, it solves my rendering issues, as you can see on the images below.

Before :

[image: 3d model with rendering errors]

After :

[image: 3d model rendering as expected]